# How to use Jmeter to iterate over multiple parameters and get the results under each parameter combination?

Tags: testing, jmeter

I want to use Jmeter to do a test with multiple parameters. Each parameter tested will be compared horizontally, so I will traverse each parameter. For example, parameter A traverses from 0 to 99, and parameter B traverses from 1 to 5. There are 500 tests in total. I know that Jmeter provides such components as Loop Controller and CSV Data Config Set, but when I try to obtain the results of one of the tests, I try several methods and fail. The test results, such as the results of the result tree or the resource monitoring plug-in PerfMon, contain 500 results.This is not what I want. What I want is the result of each parameter combination, such as A=0 and B=4.
I tried some methods, such as using Test Fragment and Include Controller, to separate the test code from the loop, which seems to be impossible.

Answer (score 0):

If parameters are simple numeric ranges you can just go for 2 [Loop Controllers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) called `A` and `B`

Then inside the Loop Controller `B` you can access:

- Parameter A as `${__jm__A__idx}`
- Parameter B as `${__intSum(${__jm__B__idx},1,)}`

The [__intSum() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__intSum) is needed to increment "B" Loop Controller index as it's zero-based. Check out [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-functions) for more information on this and other JMeter Functions.

Demo:

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I may not have expressed my question clearly. I follow your example, but I want to monitor resource consumption during testing. I need to use PerfMon, a plug-in of Jmeter. I add a listener, but it starts monitoring from the beginning of the test. What I want is to start every time I loop, and save the results of this loop to the csv file separately. I want to set the result file name of each loop to A: ${idx_A} - B: ${idx_B}. csv. Such as A:22-B:33.csv , A:22-B:34.csv  ... But I finally got only one file: A: ${idx_A} - B: ${idx_B} csv. It seems that the variable does not work at all.